# Loop stops even though only 1 of 2 variables is true

Tags: python, python-3.x, brainfuck

So I'm attempting to make a Brainfuck interpreter, however in the while loop that I am using to execute the Brainfuck loop, it is breaking out even though only one condition is true.

Example:

```
+++[>+<-]
```

Should result in:

```
[0, 3]
```

However, when the loop begins at `[`, it will create a new cell so the structure goes from `[3]` to `[3, 0]`. Thus, the current working cell is `0` and the loop is breaking out. However, I have it to only break if it is `0` and the current character is `]`.

```
cells = [0] # Array of data cells in use
brainfuck = str(input("Input Brainfuck Code: ")) # Brainfuck code
workingCell = 0 # Data pointer position
count = 0 # Current position in code
def commands(command):
    global cells
    global workingCell
    if command == ">":
        workingCell += 1
        if workingCell > len(cells) - 1:
            cells.append(0)
    elif command == "<":
        workingCell -= 1
    elif command == "+":
        cells[workingCell] += 1
    elif command == "-":
        cells[workingCell] -= 1
    elif command == ".":
        print(chr(cells[workingCell]))
    elif command == ",":
        cells[workingCell] = int(input("Input: "))
def looper(count):
    global cells
    global workingCell
    print("START LOOP", count)
    count += 1
    looper = loopStart = count
    while brainfuck[looper] != "]" and cells[workingCell] != 0: # This line is causing trouble
        if brainfuck[looper] == "]":
            looper = loopStart
        commands(brainfuck[looper])
        count += 1
        looper += 1
    return count
while count < len(brainfuck):
    if brainfuck[count] == "[":
        count = looper(count)
        print("END LOOP", count)
    else:
        commands(brainfuck[count])
    count += 1
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the logic behind `+++[>+<-]` -> `[0, 3]` ?

Comment: *"Excuse all the print statements"* - no, it's part of your job to reduce the code to a [mcve], not just dump it on us as-is.

Comment: You are using the same name for a function and a variable?!?

Comment: @anonymous +++[>+<-] just adds 3 to the first cell and then moves three into a second cell, as an example.

Comment: @johnrsharpe Without the print statements, it'll be hard for you to actually view what's happening in the code, as there is no output

Comment: You're also using the same variable name for a parameter and a global value

Comment: `looper, loopStart = count` What is this line supposed to do? Isn't `count` an integer? Should this be `looper = loopStart = count`? And do you reall want to redefine the name the function is bound to?

Comment: The loop runs once and breaks stops because of `cells[workingCell] = 0`. I think you should better specify what exactly the output should be - and what it is.

Comment: **I have it to only break if it is 0 and the current character is ].** I think you need to review [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). You're breaking if either of these is true, not when both are true.

Answer (score 1):

**I have it to only break if it is `0` and the current character is `]`**

If that's what you want, you have the logic in your `while` wrong. It should be:

```
while not (brainfuck[looper] == "]" and cells[workingCell] == 0):
```

And according to [deMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), when you distribute `not` across `and`, you invert each of the conditions and change `and` to `or`, so it should be:

```
while brainfuck[looper] != "]" or cells[workingCell] != 0:
```

If this is confusing, you could just write:

```
while True:
    if brainfuck[looper] == "]" and cells[workingCell] == 0:
        break
```

This mirrors what you said in the description exactly.